# ios/mobile: fixed div height, not zoomable?

Tags: ios, css, mobile

If I'm having a `position:fixed` div - is it possible to make it "not zoomable", even when the rest of the website can be zoomed?

I want to have a fixed height & width which always stays on bottom of the website with the same size (so the content remains the same and doesnt get zoomed with the rest of the website).

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking no that is not possible, at least not as simply as you wish.
Here is an approach that may work through. bind an event to ongesturechange of the window like so:

```
 $(window).bind("gesturechange", function(event) {
     var scale = event.originalEvent.scale;
     //Now resize your element with javascript based on the value of scale.
 });
```